# error":["function obs_getdemographicsnapshot(geometry) does not exist"]

Tags: postgresql, carto, error, api

I keep receiving this error whenever I try to use this API call:

```
https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT+*+FROM+OBS_GetDemographicSnapshot(CDB_LatLng(40.760410,-73.964242))
```

I do use my username at the front so that is correct, however I don't know how to change the url so that it will work. Is there further documentation I could use to get a more in depth understanding? The basic documentation for this paticular api isn't that great with saying how I should be using functions.

```
Here is the complete error:
{"error":["function obs_getdemographicsnapshot(geometry) does not exist"],"hint":"No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your API Key as parameter to your API call. This works for me:

```
https://{{USER_NAME}}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT+*+FROM+OBS_GetDemographicSnapshot(CDB_LatLng(40.760410,-73.964242))&api_key={{API_KEY}}
```

[image]

I will pass your feedback to CARTO's developers in order to improve [our documentation](https://carto.com/developers/data-services-api/reference/#demographic-functions) (I work at CARTO).